# Build an APK on unity using a command on the terminal

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

I have a project on Unity3d (working on a mac) and I am trying to generate the android apk file from the command line. Is this doable?

Right now I have a PerformBuild.cs file inside Assets/Editor

and I call inside it:

```
BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenes, path, BuildTarget.Android, BuildOptions.AcceptExternalModificationsToPlayer);
```

However this is only generating the Android Project for it, and not the apk.

Can I directly generate the APK using a cs build script or will I have to generate the project, import it to eclipse and then build the apk?

Thank you

Additional information:

Here is the full method in my script

```
[UnityEditor.MenuItem("CUSTOM/Test Android Build Step")]
static void androidBuild ()
{
    Debug.Log("Command line build android version\n------------------\n------------------");

    string[] scenes = GetBuildScenes();
    string path = GetBuildPathAndroid();
    if(scenes == null || scenes.Length==0 || path == null)
        return;

    Debug.Log(string.Format("Path: \"{0}\"", path));
    for(int i=0; i<scenes.Length; ++i)
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("Scene[{0}]: \"{1}\"", i, scenes[i]));
    }

    Debug.Log("Starting Android Build!");
    BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenes, path, BuildTarget.Android, BuildOptions.AcceptExternalModificationsToPlayer);
    BuildPipeline.buil
}
```

and I call it from the command line using the following:

```
/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity -batchmode -quit -executeMethod PerformBuild.androidBuild
```

and I have the android sdk setup and configured

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove `AcceptExternalModificationsToPlayer` from the `BuildOptions`.

> **BuildOptions.AcceptExternalModificationsToPlayer**
>
> On Android, this setting will create a new Eclipse project. Existing Eclipse project setting changes will be discarded.

Source:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildOptions.AcceptExternalModificationsToPlayer.html

Ok, I must admit, it's not 100% clear from this, but this is the "switch" to change, to build directly an `.apk` file instead of creating an Android project.

So in your case, just change

```
BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenes, path, BuildTarget.Android, BuildOptions.AcceptExternalModificationsToPlayer);
```

to

```
BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenes, path, BuildTarget.Android, BuildOptions.None);
```

You may want to take a look at all the different `BuildOptions` e.g. if you want to make your build debuggable (to be able to attach the MonoDevelop debugger to it => `BuildOptions.Development | BuildOptions.AllowDebugging`)

Source:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildOptions.html

Comment: How will I create release builds? how can I specify version code version name and signing key etc.

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but I think you just don't set `BuildOptions.Development`. For the version code etc. check this out: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.Android.html

Answer (score -2):

d4Rk is right, buil doption should be set to none, unless you know what you are doing.
I encountered same issue recently, searched and drilled for one day. 
Just found a special line in my build tool script:

```
EditorUserBuildSettings.exportAsGoogleAndroidProject = true;
```

I don't remember when I wrote it.. so just commented it and the buildpipeline build apk agian..